# Conditional joint probability of a function

Tags: probability

My problem is: $Y$ is a random variable exponentially distributed with mean $λ$ and $X$ is a discrete random variable such that $P(X=x_j)=\frac{1}{F}$, where $F$ is the number of elements. For example if $F=5$, then $X=[1, 19, 50, 1000, 3000]$. Now I am seeking to compute the expectation of this function $$g(X,Y)=\frac{1}{(e^{x/y}-1)^{2/a}}$$ of the random variable $Y$ conditional on $X$. Is this possible? Can we think of a "joint distribution" of two random variables where one random variable has a continuous density function and the other is discrete?

I need to find a closed form expression of the expected value

Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the definition of $X$.

Comment: X is a discrete random varibale , and there just an example X={x1,x2,..,xF}

Comment: What is the relation between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: we can say there are independent variables

Answer (score 1):

> Can we think of a "joint distribution" of two random variables where one random variable has a continuous density function and the other is discrete?

Yes, it's called a "[mixed joint probability function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case)"

$$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(x,y) & = \mathsf P(X=x\mid Y=y)\,f_Y(y)
\\ & = \mathsf P(X=x)\,f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\end{align}$$

> I need to find a closed form expression of the expected value

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(g(X,Y)) & = \sum_{x\in \{1,19,50,1000,3000\}} \int_0^\infty g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex] & = \frac 1 5 \sum_{x\in \{1,19,50,1000,3000\}} \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda}{e^{-\lambda y}(e^{x/y}-1)^{2/a}}\operatorname d y & \textsf{iff independent}
\end{align}$$

> Is this possible?

Hard to say.   The integral does not seem very easy to evaluate.   It does not look promising at all.

Comment: In the comments, the OP mentioned we can assume the random variables are independent.

Comment: Well you were asking the OP to specify the joint distribution or one conditional... which the OP did. Whether the integral has a closed form is a separate issue.

Comment: i can not find the joint distribution, my expression is

Comment: $p_j=A*E[(\frac{1}{e^{(xj/y}-1})^{2/a}]$

Comment: I look for a closed form?

Comment: Graham Kemp , thanks but how i integrate E(g(X,Y)) in your answer please